# Which of the following C data structures uses more memory?

Tags: c, memory

```
struct {char c; int i;} A[100];                                      
struct {char c[100]; int i[100];} B;
```

I need to minimize the amount of memory used. Which of these uses less and why?

Comment: What did printing the size of A and B tell you?

Answer (score 1):

The second one typically uses less.

The first one, due to alignment constraints, is likely to make an eight byte struct, using 800 bytes total for 100 copies of it; one byte for the `char`, three bytes for padding, four for the `int`.

The second one doesn't need padding for alignment (the `char` array ends at a four byte alignment), and just allocates 100 bytes, then four hundred bytes for a total of 500 bytes of memory used.

This assumes `int` is four bytes, which is by far the most common case; adjust as needed for weirdo systems.